# How to create QueryDSL Predicate from an object having a field type List?

Tags: java, spring-boot, querydsl, predicate

Having the following class

```
public class WRequest{
    String name;
    List<Integer> countries;
}
```

I try to build a predicate :

```
BooleanBuilder builder = new BooleanBuilder();
Optional.ofNullable(wrequest.getName())
        .map(QWRequest.wrequest.name::eq).ifPresent(builder::and);
```

And this works for **name** parameter only. How to build a Predicate if a field in the class is type List?

Comment: hmm, I don't seem to get the point of your question. What do you try to achive and what is the context? Also where does QWRequest come from?

Comment: QWRequest class is autogenerated Querydsl query type for WRequest class. This predicate I'm going to pass to spring data findAll() method

Comment: The desired semantics are unclear. Are you looking for "any" or "all"?

Comment: "any" is what i need